# what should i change in my function so it calculates real numbers?

Tags: c, floating-point

i am trying to write a function that repeatedly adds 0.001 to 't' and then plugs it into 'y' until 't' reaches 0.3 however the numbers come out wrong, but i've noticed that if i change float to int and change the numbers to integer, the fuction works.. what should i change so the function works properly

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void main(void)
{
    float t,y,dt;

    dt = 0.001;
    y = 1;
    t = 0;

    while (t <= 0.3)
    {
        y = y + dt*(sin(y)+(t)*(t)*(t));
        t = t + dt;
    }

    printf("y is %d when t is 0.3\n" , y);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/2173917)

Comment: What do you mean by "the numbers come out wrong" ? What numbers did you expect ? What numbers did you get ?

Comment: What happens if you change `%d` to `%f` ? Do you then get the "right" number ?

Comment: Something not relative about your question, change `main` to return `int` not `void`

Comment: If you change `printf` formatting from `%d` to `%f`, maybe your output will be fixed.

Comment: Please always include the expected output as well as the printed output in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i've noticed that if i change float to int and change the numbers to integer, the fuction works.. what should i change so the function works properly

as said in a remark the problem is the way you (try to) print the value in

> ```
> printf("y is %d when t is 0.3\n" , y);
> ```

`%d` suppose the corresponding argument is an *int* and prints it as an *int*, but *y* is a *float*. Note that there is no conversion from  *float* to *int* in that case because the arguments are managed through a *varargs*

just do

```
 printf("y is %f when t is 0.3\n" , y);
```

Also change

> ```
> void main(void)
> ```

to

```
int main()
```

After the changes, compilation and execution :

```
/tmp % gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wextra f.c -lm
/tmp % ./a.out
y is 1.273792 when t is 0.3
```

---

Note that all the calculations are done in *double*, so better to replace *float* to *double* to type your vars

---

(edit) Compiling your initial code with *gcc* and the option `-Wall` signals your problems :

```
/tmp % gcc -Wall f.c -lm
f.c:4: warning: return type of 'main' is not 'int'
f.c: In function 'main':
f.c:18: warning: format '%d' expects type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'double'
f.c:19: warning: 'return' with a value, in function returning void
```

To use both -Wall and -Wextra is the better option

Comment: Why are you using `-Wextra` but not `-Wall`?

Comment: @Broman to have more than with Wall. Wextra enables some extra warning flags that are not enabled by Wall , see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Comment: Where did Werror come from? That's something completely different. My question is why you're NOT using Wall. That's highly unusual when you're using Wextra.

Comment: @Broman sorry I written Werror ... by error, I edited my remark to replace it by Wextra. _Wextra_ includes _Wall_, and does more. The more the compiler signals errors/warning the better it is

Comment: Nope, Wextra does NOT include Wall. They are separate.

Comment: Try with this program: `int main() { int x; }`

Comment: @broman please read https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html , _-Wextra :  This enables some extra warning flags that are not enabled by -Wall_

Comment: That will emit a warning with Wall, but not Wextra

Comment: Yes, nowhere does it say that it also enables everything that Wall enables. Try it out for yourself.

Comment: @Broman ahhh, you mean why I don't use Wextra *and* Wall. Effectively you are right, I supposed Wextra includes Wall but it seems not, so need to use both of htem. Thank you for the advice and sorry for my misunderstanding / quiproquo ^^

Comment: Yes that's what I mean. I would really recommend using both.

Comment: There are actually some warnings that need both to be activated. Wunused-parameter is an example. Try this code: `void foo(int x) {} int main() {}` It will not give a warning if you're only using one of Wall and Wextra.

Comment: @Broman yes, but for me that change nothing because I consider a warning as an error by myself ;-)